# Python open file from server converts string with two backslashes to string with three backslashes

Tags: python, string, file, web-applications, path

I have a python web-app, where I open a file from a server and read the file, like this:

```
with open(self.filename, 'rb') as file:
```

The string (self.filename) of the location looks like this:

```
'\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M036_A1.ESM'
```

or this (which should be equivalent):

```
r'\\cngua01ms040\D\AWACSForBIM\awacs\work\oesm\M036_A1.ESM'
```

Now, when I run the app locally, everything works fine. When I deploy the app on heroku, it gives me the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\
\M036_A1.ESM'
```

It seems as if an additional backslash is added at the beginning. How can I solve this problem, such that when opening the file, it uses the correct location (i.e. , three backslashes)?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all double slashes with single slash

```
link = '\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M036_A1.ESM'

link1 = '\\' + link.replace('\\\\','\\')
```

Comment: Hi Seyi Daniel, thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately, this does not work. I get the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M
036_A1.ESM'.
With your suggetion,it changes the string to having 2 backslashes at the start, whereas I want 3 backslashes. Because the open function should open the file from: '\\cngua01ms040\D\AWACSForBIM\awacs\work\oesm\M036A1.ESM'

Comment: It appears extra backslashes are being added to your path,  i've added an addition slash to the beginning of the the path anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error. It makes the string look like: '\\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M036_A1.ESM'. (4 backslashes at start)
Could it be something to do with the combination of using it in a web-app environment? Because, on my local host, it works just fine when I define the link as '\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M036_A1.ESM' . (3 backslashes at start)

Comment: When I print self.filename when the string is like: '\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M036_A1.ESM'. It prints it like: '\\cngua01ms040\D\AWACSForBIM\awacs\\work\oesm\M036_A1.ESM', which is correct. But once used with open(self.filename, 'rb'), somehow it is changed to '\\\\cngua01ms040\\D\\AWACSForBIM\\awacs\\work\\oesm\\M036_A1.ESM'. I believe the problem lies in the open function when used as a web-app, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Solved the issue, it had something to do with a connection to a VPN server from another server. It was unable to reach that server, but apparently this was the error message send, it was not clear at the beginning for me that the issue lay there.